# Check boost::interprocess::vector has enough capacity before writing?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am using a shared vector to share objects across memory:

```
using ShmemAllocator = bip::allocator<T, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
using MyVector = bip::vector<T, ShmemAllocator>;

bip::permissions perm;
perm.set_unrestricted();
segment.reset(new bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::open_or_create, shared_memory_name, numBytes, 0, perm));

const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment->get_segment_manager());
vec = segment->find_or_construct<MyVector>(shared_vector_name)(alloc_inst);
```

Note the vector is created within a `managed_shared_memory` object and this is created by specifying a number of bytes, not number of vector elements.

I then write elements to the vector:

```
int write(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    bip::scoped_lock<bip::named_mutex> lock(*sdc.mutex);

    for(const auto& item : vec)
    {
        sdc.vec->push_back(item);
    }

    sdc.cond_empty->notify_all();
}
```

**What is the safest way to check whether I have enough space to write all my elements, prior to writing?** I would really like to avoid simply assigning a large number of bytes and hoping I never hit it!

Comment: call `vector::reserve`?

Comment: @VTT that might fail. Checking [capacity()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) is closer already

Comment: @sehe I didn't see your comment and implemented what VTT is probably suggesting, whereby I try doing a reserve(vec.size() + newVec.size()) and if that fails, I catch and return false. Is capacity() the correct way of implementing what I ended up doing?

Comment: `capacity()` is the right way to answer the bolded question _"What is the safest way to check whether I have enough space to write all my elements, prior to writing?"_. However the backstory suggests that you want to know ***"How do I make sure my memory segment is large enough to contain my data (e.g. a vector)?"*** which is what I answered in my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Note the vector is created within a managed_shared_memory object and this is created by specifying a number of bytes, not number of vector elements

There's no straight formula as the overhead of the segment manager can be significant and depends on allocation patterns: in [this older answer I demonstrate this quite visually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287171/bad-alloc-is-thrown/21287572#21287572):

[image]

With that in mind, you can probably do some testing on the intended platform and workout the actual size required.

However, you can also forget about it, and remember **it's all virtual memory** anyways. Just reserve a TB or three, and nothing should ever get mapped/committed unless you those pages.

> If you want to use `managed_mapped_file` you can happily use `ftruncate` to create a Very Large™ sparse file (i.e. with no blocks *actually* allocated) and use it in the very same way.
>
> Not all filesystems support sparse files, but all mainstream filesystems do (NTFS, ext2/3/4 etc.). Usually if sparse files aren't supported, `mmap` isn't supported either (think network filesystems or highlevel fuse drivers)