# move boost::interprocess::string in shared memory

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I wanted to implement, some queue of messages (based on vector) to handling in some way data from the network and to do this I used shared memory to save messages and I encountered an issue related to it, the thing is that my code works well when I run it first time, when I want to run it once again I get segfaut when I want to assign a new value to string in my queue in shared memory, actually in my case when I want to move it (the same problem exists when I want to copy it). The problem doesn't exist when SSO is working, so when I have small string enough. What did I wrong ?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

struct BadSharedMemoryAccess final : public std::exception
{
    BadSharedMemoryAccess(std::string&& msg):
        msg_{std::move(msg)}
{}

virtual const char* what() const noexcept
{
    return msg_.c_str();
}

private:
    std::string msg_;
};

struct Message
{
    bip::string message_;
};

template<typename Alloc>
class MyCustomData final
{
public:
    using allocator_type = typename Alloc::template rebind<Message>::other;

    MyCustomData(std::size_t number_of_messages, Alloc alloc = {}) :
        init_add_index_{0},
        init_handle_index_{-1},
        messages_{number_of_messages, alloc}
    {}

public:
    uint_fast64_t init_add_index_;
    int_fast64_t init_handle_index_;
    std::vector<Message, Alloc> messages_;
//    bip::vector<data::Message, Alloc> messages_;
};

template<typename DataType, typename DataAllocator>
class SharedMemory
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    SharedMemory(std::string const& shm_segment_name, std::size_t const segment_size,
        std::string const& shm_object_name, Args&&... args) :
            shm_object_name_{shm_object_name}
    {
        std::cout << "attempt to allocate space for shared memory segment " << shm_segment_name
              << ", size: ." << segment_size << std::endl;
        setSharedMemorySize(shm_segment_name, segment_size);

        DataAllocator const allocInstance{shm_.get_segment_manager()};
        data_ = shm_.find_or_construct<DataType>(shm_object_name.c_str())(std::forward<Args>(args)..., allocInstance);
        if (data_)
            std::cout << "shared memory segment has been allocated" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "shared memory has not been constructed or founded" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~SharedMemory()
    {
        std::cout << "shared memory segment will be closed." << std::endl;
    }

    void setSharedMemorySize(std::string const& shm_segment_name, std::size_t const segment_size)
    {
        auto page_size = bip::mapped_region::get_page_size();
        auto const page_increase_rate{2};
        while (page_size < segment_size)
        {
            page_size *= page_increase_rate;
        }

        std::cout <<"seting page size: " << page_size << std::endl;
        shm_ = bip::managed_shared_memory{bip::open_or_create, shm_segment_name.c_str(), page_size};
        std::cout << "space for shared memory has been successfully allocated." << std::endl;
    }

    DataType& getData()
    {
        if (not data_)
            throw BadSharedMemoryAccess{"cannot access " + shm_object_name_};
        return *data_;
    }

protected:
    DataType* data_;

private:
    std::string const shm_object_name_;
    bip::managed_shared_memory shm_;
};

namespace sharable
{
    using DataAllocator = bip::allocator<Message, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
    template<typename Alloc>
    using DataType = MyCustomData<Alloc>;
}

int main()
{
    std::size_t const max_number_of_elements_in_container{1000000};
    auto shmem_data = std::make_shared<SharedMemory<MyCustomData<sharable::DataAllocator>, sharable::DataAllocator>>(
        "SHM_SEGMENT", sizeof(MyCustomData<sharable::DataAllocator>) +
            (max_number_of_elements_in_container * sizeof(Message) * 2),
        "SHM_CONTAINER", max_number_of_elements_in_container);

    std::vector<bip::string> feed{max_number_of_elements_in_container};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < max_number_of_elements_in_container; ++i)
    {
        std::string s{"blablabla11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" + std::to_string(i)};
        feed[i] = s.c_str();
    }

    auto& data = shmem_data->getData();
    auto& shmem_vec = data.messages_;
    std::cout << "addr: " << shmem_vec.data() << std::endl;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < max_number_of_elements_in_container; ++i)
    {
//        if (i == 0)
//            std::cout << "msg: " << shmem_vec[i].message_ << std::endl;
        auto msg = feed[i];
        shmem_vec[i].message_ = std::move(msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are not using a shared-memory allocator for the strings. In that sense
   your question is the same as
   [circular_buffer and managed_mapped_file segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510801/circular-buffer-and-managed-mapped-file-segmentation-fault/62515428#62515428).
   You might want to read that for a general intro.
2. Your example complicates things by wrapping the strings into your own
   structs. That means you get a lot of tedious work passing around
   allocators. For the "uses_allocator" approach which - in combination with
   `scoped_allocator_adaptor` - can alleviate some of that pain, see e.g.
   [making non-shared copies of boost::interprocess shared memory objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492147/making-non-shared-copies-of-boostinterprocess-shared-memory-objects/27500693#27500693).
3. Reading the rest of your code, I'm a bit confused. Why would you template
   your `SharedMemory` type with an allocator? I mean, the `SharedMemory`
   should be the *single point* responsible for chosing and passing the right
   allocator, right? How could it work with an externally provided allocator.
4. There are typedefs that are unused, you make a new segment for each object
   even though it might be from the same shared memory (mapping the same pages
   into memory multiple times). Yet you somehow think it's important to *share
   ownership* of one such an instance (`make_shared`).
5. The size calculations are just wrong: they only take into account the size
   of your `Message` struct, not the allocated string data. You seem to have
   forgotten that mapped memory is virtual memory too. The underlying storage
   will be able to allocate sparsely. So, why not reserve a generous amount of
   memory, and just respond when you run out?
6. You're talking about and coding (some) move semantics, but then you write:

   ```
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < max_number_of_elements_in_container; ++i) {
       auto msg = feed[i];
       shmem_vec[i].message_ = std::move(msg);
   }
   ```

   That's confused. What good is the move (if it worked, see below) if you
   first make an explicit copy anyways:

   ```
       auto msg = feed[i];
   ```
7. These are worrying signs:

   ```
   uint_fast64_t init_add_index_;
   int_fast64_t  init_handle_index_;
   ```

   It looks as if you may be planning to use these concurrently from multiple
   processes/threads². In such case, you must add synchronization OR use
   `atomic<>` types at the very least.

***Summarizing*** it looks to me that you may be trying so hard to hide
complexity that you accidentally increased it.

### On Moving

You ask about "moving shared string in shared memory". For this part of the
question, let's assume you actually had your strings allocating in shared
memory.

Looking at how moving strings works it's not hard to see that moving strings
*inside shared memory* will work exactly like moving them *inside the heap*
would work: the object address will be different, but the internal pointer to
allocated memory will be the same.

However, the code does ***something else***: It doesn't move *inside* shared
memory. It attempts to move **from** heap **to** shared memory. ***This will
obviously not be safe*** since the objects in shared memory cannot usefully point to
anything outside the shared memory segment (any other process would invoke
undefined behaviour indirecting through such a pointer).

As often, in C++ you're partly your own to prevent accidents like this: [C++11
`basic_string<>::swap`](http://The%20behavior%20is%20undefined%20if%20Allocator%20does%20not%20propagate%20on%20swap%20and%20the%20allocators%20of%20*this%20and%20other%20are%20unequal.) specifies

> The behavior is undefined if `Allocator` does not propagate on swap and the
> allocators of `*this` and `other` are unequal.

The move-constructor [is specified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) to have complexity:

> constant. If alloc is given and alloc != other.get_allocator(), then linear

Note that the semantics of allocators when copying/moving containers (`basic_string<>` is a container, similar to `std::vector<>`) is even more involved:

[image]

#### What To Do?

All in all, if you're lucky the move won't compile because the allocators are of incompatible types and none is supplied (e.g. by the uses_allocator protocol).

If you're less lucky, it will compile but it will (fortunately) not perform the move because it detects that the allocators are "not equal" and hence it falls back to copying the storage.

If you're absolutely unlucky, you chose a configuration where the types are compatible and the allocators are not configured to safely propagate on container move/copy, or another circumstance leads the allocators to fail to detect "incompatibility"¹, and you end up with UB.

In this case there's a much easier option: **you know you can't move**. Hence, **don't request a move**.

Risk averted.

### Some Code To Heal Our Wounds

After breaking down a lot of the complexity in the code and question, let's get constructive and show what we can do to fix things:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

struct BadSharedMemoryAccess final : std::runtime_error {
    BadSharedMemoryAccess(std::string msg) : std::runtime_error{ std::move(msg) } {}
};
```

That's the prelude. Now, let's state our intentions:

```
using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
template <typename U> using Alloc = bip::allocator<U, Segment::segment_manager>;
```

This makes it easy to refer to (and maybe switch out) the segment and its allocators.

```
using Message       = bip::string;
using Feed          = bip::vector<Message>;
using SharedMessage = bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char> >;
using SharedFeed    = bip::vector<SharedMessage, Alloc<SharedMessage> >;
```

Simply define our domain entities.
By using `bip::string`/`bip::vector` for heap and shared allocation versions we get the best interop between the two;

```
class MyCustomData final {
  public:
    using allocator_type = SharedFeed::allocator_type;

    MyCustomData(std::size_t capacity, allocator_type alloc)
        : messages_(capacity, SharedMessage(alloc), alloc) // don't brace initlaize
    { }

    auto&       messages()       { return messages_; }
    auto const& messages() const { return messages_; }

  private:
    uint_fast64_t init_add_index_ = 0;
    int_fast64_t  init_handle_index_ = -1;
    SharedFeed messages_;
};
```

> For now, dropped the `virtual` destructor, and the `Message` struct that simply wrapped a `bip::string` for convenience.

```
template <typename T> class SharedMemory final {
  public:
    template <typename... Args>
    SharedMemory(std::string const& shm_segment_name,
                 std::size_t const segment_size,
                 std::string const& shm_object_name,
                 Args&&... args)
        : shm_ { bip::open_or_create, shm_segment_name.c_str(), segment_size }
    {
        data_ = shm_.find_or_construct<T>
            (shm_object_name.c_str())
            (std::forward<Args>(args)...,
             shm_.get_segment_manager())
            ;

        if (!data_) throw BadSharedMemoryAccess {"cannot access " + shm_segment_name + "/" + shm_object_name};
    }

    T const& get() const { return *data_; }
    T&       get()       { return *data_; }

    auto free() const { return shm_.get_free_memory(); }
  protected:
    T* data_;

  private:
    Segment shm_;
};
```

> It strikes me that `SharedMemory` has too many responsibilities: on the one
> hand it tries to be a "smart-reference" for shared objects, and on the other
> hand it "manages a segment". This leads to problems if you actually wanted to
> have multiple objects in a segment. Consider splitting into `Shared::Segment`
> and `Shared::Object<T>`.

```
Feed generate_heap_feed(size_t n) {
    Feed feed;
    feed.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n ; ++i) {
        feed.emplace_back(
            "blablabla11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
            + std::to_string(i));
    }
    return feed;
}
```

Extracted the test-feed generator from `main`.

```
int main() {
    static constexpr std::size_t capacity { 1000000 };
    static constexpr auto estimate = 300ull << 20; // 300 MiB (<< 10 kilo, << 20 mebi, << 30 gibi)
```

Replaced the misguided calculations³ with a generous estimate. See measurements below.

```
    using SharedData = SharedMemory<MyCustomData>;
    SharedData shmem_data("SHM_SEGMENT", estimate, "SHM_CONTAINER", capacity);
    std::cout << "Free: " << shmem_data.free() << "\n";
```

Nice and readable. On my system prints `"Free: 282572448"` on first run.

```
    Feed const feed      = generate_heap_feed(capacity);
    SharedFeed& shm_feed = shmem_data.get().messages();
```

Now we have our feeds side by side, let's copy:

```
    // copy feed from heap to shm
    auto const n = std::min(feed.size(), shm_feed.size());
    std::copy_n(feed.begin(), n, shm_feed.begin());

    std::cout << "Copied: " << n << "\n";
    std::cout << "Free: " << shmem_data.free() << "\n";
```

That's all. We don't try to move, because we know that can't work.
`bip::basic_string` correctly knows how to copy between incompatible allocators. No sweat.

For good measure let's print some diagnostic information:

```
    {
        // check some random samples
        std::default_random_engine prng{std::random_device{}()};
        auto pick = [&] { return std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, n-1)(prng); };

        for (auto index : {pick(), pick(), pick(), pick()}) {
            std::string_view a = feed.at(index);
            std::string_view b = shm_feed.at(index);
            std::cout << "Message #" << index
                << (a == b? " OK":" FAIL")
                << " " << std::quoted(b) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru⁴](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbfb91179585c8ae)**

Prints, e.g.:
[image]

> Especially note the filesize measurements (`--apparent-size` vs. the size on
> disk). This confirms my point about sparse allocation. Even if you reserved
> 100TB, the effective size of the SHM_CONTAINER would still be
> 182MiB.

## BONUS SECTIONS

#### Scoped Allocator Adaptors

Simply replacing one line:

```
template <typename U> using Alloc = bip::allocator<U, Segment::segment_manager>;
```

with

```
template <typename U> using Alloc = boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor<
    bip::allocator<U, Segment::segment_manager> >;
```

does the trick, unlocking magical allocator propagation, e.g. from vector to
string when constructing its elements (with `emplace` or `assign`). So we can
simplify the `copy_n` even more from:

```
// copy feed from heap to shm
auto const n = std::min(feed.size(), shm_feed.size());
std::copy_n(feed.begin(), n, shm_feed.begin());

std::cout << "Copied: " << n << "\n";
```

to simply:

```
shm_feed.assign(feed.begin(), feed.end());
std::cout << "Copied: " << shm_feed.size() << "\n";
```

It has exactly the same allocation behaviour as before.
See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5d1f5c445af728d)** as well.

#### Polymorphic Allocators (c++17)

This would not change a thing, fundamentally, except:

- it would make Feed/SharedFeed and Message/SharedMessage share the same static type
- it would have the scoped-allocator behaviour as before by default

However, until we get proper support for fancy pointers in the standard, this is a pipe dream:

- [polymorphic_allocator: when and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010544/polymorphic-allocator-when-and-why-should-i-use-it/55294510#55294510)

  > This is a key point and a big bummer. Arthur O'Dwyer's [Towards meaningful fancy pointers](https://quuxplusone.github.io/draft/fancy-pointers.html) paper explores the territory, as does [his book "Mastering the c++17 STL"](https://books.google.nl/books?id=zJlGDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA231&ots=O0fQUCYSa-&dq=pmr%20offset_ptr&pg=PA231#v=onepage&q=pmr%20offset_ptr&f=false)

#### Making `Message` Struct Again?

Well. More like "struggle again". I admit that I hate writing allocator-aware data types. This is no doubt not optimal, but it is the minimal thing I could do to make things working:

```
template <typename Alloc>
struct BasicMessage {
    // pre-c++17:
    //  using allocator_type = typename Alloc::template rebind<char>::other;
    using allocator_type = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<char>;

    BasicMessage(std::allocator_arg_t, allocator_type alloc)
        : _msg(alloc) { }

    template <typename T1, typename... T,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<
                    not std::is_same_v<std::allocator_arg_t, std::decay_t<T1> >
                 >
        >
    explicit BasicMessage(T1&& a, T&&... init)
        : _msg(std::forward<T1>(a), std::forward<T>(init)...) { }

    template <typename OtherAlloc>
    BasicMessage(BasicMessage<OtherAlloc> const& other, allocator_type alloc)
        : _msg(other.message().begin(), other.message().end(), alloc) { }

    template <typename OtherAlloc, typename OM = BasicMessage<OtherAlloc> >
    std::enable_if_t<
        not std::is_same_v<allocator_type, typename OM::allocator_type>,
        BasicMessage&>
    operator=(BasicMessage<OtherAlloc> const& other) {
        _msg.assign(other.message().begin(), other.message().end());
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename OtherAlloc>
    BasicMessage(std::allocator_arg_t, allocator_type alloc, BasicMessage<OtherAlloc> const& other)
        : _msg(other.message().begin(), other.message().end(), alloc) { }

    BasicMessage(BasicMessage const&) = default;
    BasicMessage(BasicMessage&&) = default;
    BasicMessage& operator=(BasicMessage const&) = default;
    BasicMessage& operator=(BasicMessage&&) = default;

    auto& message() const { return _msg; }
    auto& message()       { return _msg; }
  private:
    bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, allocator_type> _msg;
};

using Message       = BasicMessage<std::allocator<char> >;
using Feed          = bip::vector<Message>;
using SharedMessage = BasicMessage<Alloc<char> >;
using SharedFeed    = bip::vector<SharedMessage, Alloc<SharedMessage> >;
```

On the bright side, that still uses the "magic assign" due to the
scoped_allocator_adaptor fix introduced above. Perhaps if that wasn't desired,
you could get away with a little bit less complexity.

With minor interface changes elsewhere:

```
: messages_(capacity, SharedMessage(std::allocator_arg, alloc), alloc) // don't brace initlaize
```

and

```
    std::string_view a = feed.at(index).message();
    std::string_view b = shm_feed.at(index).message();
```

it all still works, see **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfe52cfaf3417946)**

---

¹ not standardese, hence the scare-quotes

² I'm suspecting you may be trying to implement the Disruptor Pattern

³ see [Estimating size required for memory mapped boost rtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62339977/estimating-size-required-for-memory-mapped-boost-rtree/62344284#62344284)

⁴ replaced `managed_shared_memory` with `manage_mapped_file` and reduced capacities`because of Coliru limitations

Comment: Added the bonus sections

Comment: Sehe, thank you very much for your valuable thoughts. Just couple of questions:
1.Is that mean that I should perform a couple of runs to determine how much shared memory I should allocate ? because I thought that this can be configurable e.g. by users in some config file, you know base e.g. on max number of messages.

Comment: 2.If I understand it correctly boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor works like pmr ?

Comment: 3.Just for curiosity when I want to use strings in shmem, why I need to declare as you wrote bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, allocator_type> instead of bip::string ? I thought that bip::string is designed for that purpose.

Comment: @bladzio ~Out of curiosity~ Socratic mode engaged: 3. why do ask about `bip::string`, but not about `bip::vector` - where you ***did*** specify an allocator? What allocator would `bip::string` use if it came pre-wired? What kind of a segment_manager would it be typed with?

Comment: 2, No. PMR makes it so that the static allocator type is the same for different memory resources. Scoped allocators allow containers to pass their allocator along to their elements for construction (e.g. on emplace). PMR _shares _ that behaviour (it is assumed that your elements would also use PMR, which makes a lot of sense)

Comment: 1. My stance is that you should normally be free to overdimension (barring file-systems without sparse file support, RTOS without virtual memory or stringent ulimit sandboxes, in which case you'd probably not be using shared mem). If you must, then indeed profile memory usage. I have some answers on [SO] profiling shared memory usage (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62344284/85371) and also some answers about growing segments

Comment: ad.3 - I thought that an allocator provided to vector will be used by bip::string :P
4. I'm wondering why in MyCustomData constructor during calling SharedFeed constructor you did 
messages_(capacity, SharedMessage(std::allocator_arg, alloc), alloc) ? I mean why not
messages_(capacity, alloc) instead ?

Comment: @bladzio It's just an overload that exists to disambiguate the allocator argument. It's useful in general for generic code, and also instructive here because it **is** what the uses-allocator-construction ends up doing (e.g. when emplacing into a container).

Comment: thanks very much for explanation. I tried adopt your tips to do next step and implement nested structures in shared memory, but it doesn't even compile [Iink](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7170ef42bde1e50). Compiler is not able to find appropriate constructor but why ?